# Filezilla installed on a Parallels' Virtual Machine connects but does not retrieve directories

Tags: mac, virtual-machine, ftp, parallels, filezilla

I have Windows XP Service Pack 3 installed on a Mac running Parallels 6.
Everything works fine except for FTP programmes (ie Filezilla, CoreFTP etc). If I connect from my Mac directly using Filezilla (not from virtual machine) everything works fine.

Below is the status report that I get from Filezilla 3.4.0 when I try to connect to my server.

I hope someone can help.

Many thanks,

Giuseppe

```
Status: Resolving address of www.xxxxxxx.com
Status: Connecting to XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Gene6 FTP Server v3.10.0 (Build 2) ready...
Command:    USER xxxxxxx
Response:   331 Password required for webdev.
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   230 User webdev logged in.
Command:    SYST
Response:   215 UNIX Type: L8
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Extensions supported:
Response:    AUTH TLS
Response:    CCC
Response:    CLNT
Response:    CPSV
Response:    EPRT
Response:    EPSV
Response:    MDTM
Response:    MFCT
Response:    MFMT
Response:    MLST type*;size*;create;modify*;
Response:    MODE Z
Response:    PASV
Response:    PBSZ
Response:    PROT
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:    SIZE
Response:    SSCN
Response:    TVFS
Response:    UTF8
Response:    XCRC "filename" SP EP
Response:    XMD5 "filename" SP EP
Response:    XSHA1 "filename" SP EP
Response:   211 End.
Command:    CLNT FileZilla
Response:   200 Noted.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 UTF8 OPTS ON
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (82,196,228,233,151,45)
Command:    MLSD
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Comment: I don't know Parallels, but my guess would be that it (or Windows) blocks some ports (which need to be open for passive FTP transmissions).

Comment: @slhck I tried disabling the Windows Firewall without success. I don't believe Parallels has any port configuration, I will double check. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK I found out what it was, it was OSX's firewall that was blocking it!

Thank you @slhck for the hint on the ports.

Comment: Ok, let me put that as an answer then ;)

Answer (score 0):

For FTP connections you need to have certain ports open. In the following order, check if there are firewalls blocking it:

- OS X
- Parallels (I don't know if it has something like that)
- Windows XP

Comment: Do you know how to open specific port on a Snow Leopard? It seems that apart from adding an application the the rules (which I did with Parallels but did not work) there is no interface for adding a specific port. I cannot get Filezilla to work with the Mac's Firewall on and I don't want to switch off my Mac's Firewall!?

Comment: @Giuseppe Hm, I think Parallels.app is not the main application where traffic goes through. There must be some service running in the background for network traffic. That might just be worth another question ("How to disable OS X firewall for Parallels only"). I unfortunately can't try it because I don't have Parallels.